# Pass through SOAP proxy spring Unsupported media type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary

Tags: spring, soap, content-type, spring-restcontroller, mtom

Hi I am trying to implement a pass through SOAP proxy via @RestController in spring. For this purpose I have mapped a rest controller in following way:

```
@RestController
class MyProxy {

@PostMapping(value = "/**")  
  public ResponseEntity<String> proxyPost(@RequestBody(required = false) String body, HttpServletRequest request) {}
}
```

The regular SOAP requests are going OK. The problem comes when a MTOM type of SOAP request is send via the proxy. Then spring failes with unrecognized content type. Here is the exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: Unsupported Content-Type [multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:dacf4733-80b4-41bc-b2e1-db69b6beadf6"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"], expected [multipart/form-data]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Unsupported Content-Type [multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:dacf4733-80b4-41bc-b2e1-db69b6beadf6"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"], expected [multipart/form-data]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2407)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:317)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Disable file uploads.

Comment: @M.Deinum explain please? I am not getting your thought.

Comment: Are you talking about that ? spring.servlet.multipart.enabled

Comment: It is a multipart request (when using MTOM) hence the fileupload (also multipart) tries to parse the request. You don't want this as you want to just pass through. Ergo disable file upload to prevent parsing.

Comment: @M.Deinum this property ?  spring.servlet.multipart.enabled

Comment: That one, that should be `false` unless you are doing file uploads in your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hei thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When receiving a `multipart/*` request Spring delegates this to the configured Multipart handler. This is enabled by default and for this case should be disabled.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```

Adding the above to your properties should disable it and prevent the parsing, so you can handle it in your controller.